# Qt c++ Передача значений по кнопке

Tags: c++, qt, datetime, combobox

Привет Всем. Есть Форма ui на ней есть comboBox и два QDateTime. Нужно чтобы по нажатию кнопки ui->push_button_Ok эти значения передавались в функцию. В дальнейшем с ними будет производится работа в функции. Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: А что мешает считать эти значения в обработчике?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Присоединить к сигналу нажатия кнопки слот. Внутри слота поместить данные из виджетов в переменные и вызвать функцию:

```
void onPushPressed() {
    auto dateTime1 = mDateTimeWidget1.dateTime();
    auto dateTime2 = mDateTimeWidget2.dateTime();
    auto comboValue = mComboBox.currentText();
    foo(dateTime1, dateTime2, comboValue);
}
```